# Dealing with mass images, some small - some large, in spring/java application using mysql

Tags: mysql, image, spring, file, avatar

I was wondering what the best pattern was to handle the management of images these days when using spring/java and mysql.

1. I have several options. Some of the
   images are just small avatars for
   the users. Is it fine to put these
   directly into mysql? Or use the file
   system?
2. For the larger images, is file
   system pretty much the only option,
   and then use mysql to store the
   location on the file system?
3. Where is a good spot to put them on
   a linux server? /var/files/images?
4. Since the files are hidden from the
   war deployment directory, what is
   the best way to stream them? Use
   some kind of a file output stream as
   the response body for an http
   request?
5. Also, do I have to develop all of
   the file management stuff myself,
   like cleaning up unused files and
   the like?
6. What about image security? Some images should not be accessed by everyone. I think I'd need to use a separate url with Spring security checking the current user for this.

I'd appreciate advice on all of these questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use MySQL, and that would have the advantage of centralization and easy cleanup, but IMHO it's a waste of the database's resources if you plan to scale.

For data like images where everything is public, consider something like Amazon S3 which allows you to serve images directly from S3's web servers. If you plan to host everything yourself, just serve from a directory. Just remember to turn directory listings off :)

Comment: Can you eliberate on what you mean by turning directory listings off? Also, wouldn't putting anything in the deployment directory be dangerous? I don't want tomcat to delete the directory containing the images. Also, some of these images WILL NOT be public. I.e. they are company images that only people who belong to that company should have access to.

Comment: As for cleanup, would I just read the directory of images, and then read all the locations in the various tables in the database, do a comparison, and delete all the ones not in the database tables? I have about 6 or 7 entities (tables) that use images currently.

Comment: Also, would it be better to put them on an image hosting server... separate from the application server?